# displaying a ViewBag list on cshtml after creating a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("postNewBasketballPlayer")]
public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer(int newParticipantId)
{
ViewModel.Participant newP = db.Participants.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ParticipantId == newParticipantId);
if(newP != null)
{    
     var timespan = DateTime.Now - newP.ParticipantDOB;
     //this block of code is also repeated for newP.ParticipantGender == "Female"
     if(newP.ParticipantGender == "Male")
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Male basketball player");
             //this block of code repeates for different age groups
             if(timespan.TotalDays>=(7*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(9*365))
             {
                 League LeaguebbM7and8 = db.Leagues.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.gender == "Male" && i.ageRange == "7and8" && i.sport == "Basketball");
                 //if the League doesn't exist it creates it
                 if(LeaguebbM7and8 == null)
                 {
                     LeaguebbM7and8 = new League()
                     {
                         sport = "Basketball",
                         gender = "Male",
                         ageRange = "7and8"
                     };
                     db.Add(LeaguebbM7and8);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     Console.WriteLine("made new league LeaguebbM7and8");

                     MMLeagueParticipant MMbbM7and8 = new MMLeagueParticipant()
                     {
                         ParticipantId = newParticipantId,
                         LeagueId = LeaguebbM7and8.LeagueId
                     };
                     //adds a row to table with the id's
                     db.Add(MMbbM7and8);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     Console.WriteLine("added to LeaguebbM7and8");
                 }
                 //if the league exists; it simply adds it. 
                 else
                 {
                     //each time i add a child. it needs its own middle table (reason for new)
                     MMLeagueParticipant MMbbM7and8 = new MMLeagueParticipant()
                     {
                         ParticipantId = newParticipantId,
                         LeagueId = LeaguebbM7and8.LeagueId
                     };
                     db.Add(MMbbM7and8);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     Console.WriteLine("added to LeaguebbM7and8");
                 }
                 Console.WriteLine("returning to dashboard (LeaguebbM7and8)");
                 return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
             }
             //this code is repeated for multiple age checks as above.
             //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(9*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(11*365)){...}
             //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(11*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(13*365)){...}
             //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(13*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(15*365)){...}
             //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(15*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(17*365)){...}
             //else if(timespan.TotalDays>=(17*365) && timespan.TotalDays<(19*365)){...}
         }
     //repeates the block of code above for all the age check if female.
     //if(newP.ParticipantGender == "Female)...
 }
 if(newP == null)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("id passed in was null");
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
 }
 Console.WriteLine("skips all if checks because newP was null");
 return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
```

}

what im doing

- passing in an id
- if id matches an id of a participant, i check the gender of the participant
- then check the age of the participant
- then check if a league model exists for those criterias. if it doesn't i create a league model for that gender and age group
- i then create a new many-to-many model where participantId = the the id passed into the model and a leagueId = the id of the league model i just created
- however if the league model already exists for the age group/gender; I will simply just add the many-to-many model

what my terminal reads when LeaguebbM7and8 is null:

```
    newParticipantId
    15
    newP
    LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel+Participant
    Male basketball player
    made new league LeaguebbM7and8
    added to LeaguebbM7and8
    returning to dashboard (LeaguebbM7and8)
```

what my terminal reads when LeaguebbM7and8 is not null:

```
newParticipantId
15
newP
LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel+Participant
Male basketball player
added to LeaguebbM7and8
returning to dashboard (LeaguebbM7and8)
```

my league model:

- int LeagueId { get; set; }
- string sport { get; set; }
- string gender { get; set; }
- string ageRange { get; set; }
- ​List<MMLeagueParticipant> allParticipants  { get; set; }        (a many to many relationship for league and participant)

my ViewModel model:

- ViewModelParticipant participant { get; set; }
- List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
- public class Participant

  - int ParticipantId { get; set; }
  - string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }
  - string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }
  - string ParticipantGender { get; set; }
  - SystemDateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }
  - List<MMLeagueParticipant> all Leagues { get; set; }

my MMLeagueParticipant middle table for the league model and ViewModel.Participant:

- int MMLeaugeParticipantId { get; set; }
- int ParticipantId { get; set; }
- int LeaugeId { get; set; }
- leauge sport { get; set; }
- ViewModel.Participant child { get; set; }

using the models listed above; I'm attempting to query and get the list of my participants by doing the following when calling the page i want to display:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("roster/basketball")]
public IActionResult BasketballRoster()
{
    //the reason im using viewbag is because its easier to work with since I can't pass multiple models in. and everything is in tabs. just makes life easier
    ViewBag.bbM7and8 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "7and8").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM7and8);

            ViewBag.bbM9and10 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "9and10").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM9and10);

    ViewBag.bbM11and12 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "11and12").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM11and12);

    ViewBag.bbM13and14 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "13and14").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM13and14);

    ViewBag.bbM15and16 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "15and16").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM15and16);

    ViewBag.bbM17and18 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "17and18").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM17and18);

    return View("RosterPageBasketball");
}
```

what the console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM7and8) displays in the terminal:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LeagueProject.Models.League]
```

My rosterpage contains different tabs. Each of tab displays "the list is empty" even though i added in LeaguebbM7and8

```
            //cshtml

            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM7and8-tab">
                    7-8
                    @{
                        //checks if list is null or the length is 0
                        if(ViewBag.bbM7and8 != null && ViewBag.Any())
                        {
                            <p>the list is not empty</p>
                            foreach(League j in ViewBag.bbM7and8)
                            {
                                foreach(MMLeagueParticipant mmLp in j.allParticipants)
                                {
                                    <p>@mmLp.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLp.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p>the list is empty</p>
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                //the above code is repeated for each tab
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM9and10-tab">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM11and12-tab">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM13and14-tab">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM15and16-tab">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM17and18-tab">
```

what i tried:

- i tried putting both foreaches under the else to see if I could do this inversely.
- - error: RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
    RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Answer (score 0):

For the start try to replace

```
if(ViewBag.bbM7and8 == null && ViewBag.Any())
 {
  ....
```

with

```
@{ var hasData=false;}

@if( ViewBag.bbM7and8 != null) 
 {
 @foreach(League j in ViewBag.bbM7and8)
   {
       @if( j.allParticipants != null) 
          {
           @foreach(MMLeagueParticipant mmLp in j.allParticipants)
             {
                 @if( mmLp.child != null) 
                  {   
                   @{hasData=true;}          
                  <p>@mmLp.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLp.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                   }

        ........
@if (!hasData)
{
 <p>the list is empty</p>
}

}
```

but IMHO all these nested loops should be done in the action, maybe another way. You have  to put in your ViewModel just the list of the first and the last names.

Comment: now the only thing displaying on my browser is 7-8. doesn't display the list or the "the list is empty" p tag.